# Not able to see the Web Automation in the Configured VM through Azure Devops Pipleine

Tags: selenium, automation, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Following steps followed
1.Configured the Agent in the VM
2.Created new Pipeline and configured the Web Automation Project to run in the VM at the specified time (5:00 PM)
3.When i open the VM at automation running time (5:00 PM). Automation Logs are created, but visually not able to see the web browser launching and executing the testcases.

Please can anyone help me on this issue to resolve.

Comment: Did you configure the agent as interactive mode? As normal, the browser would be launched automatically only when the agent is in interactive mode.

Comment: Thank you for the response.In the below steps i didnt come across setting the agent as interactive mode, how to set it?
These are the steps i followed in configuring the agent in the VM: 
1-Navigated to Project Settings in Azure Devops and click on project settings
2-Click on Add pool button and give the pool name (Test-Pool) and click on create 
3-Click on New agent button and download the respective agent
4-Copy Paste the downloaded agent to the VM and ran the Config.bat from the cmd
5-Given the Server URL and Access Token. Entered the Agent Pool Name,Agent Name and Working directory.

Comment: At the last configure steps: https://imgur.com/a/lQDZ0uH It will ask for whether you want this agent run as service? Choose No to set the agent as interactive mode.

Comment: Just want to check the latest status on this issue. Is interactive mode could help you launch the browser now?